Wieso wird das weibliche Genus weiblich genannt, wenn das Weib neutrum ist?
So wie ich grammatische Geschlechter verstehe, handelt es sich selten oder weniger um Archetypen (also z.B. darum dass “die Armee“ archetypisch Frauensache sei) sondern eher um verschiedene Wörterklassen, denen ein “Geschlecht” zugewiesen wird basierend auf ihre Ähnlichkeit mit den Wörtern für die zwei Geschlechter.
Sollte dann nicht das was man Neutrum nennt das weibliche Geschlecht sein?
Offensichtlich ist das nicht der Fall, aber wie kam es dann dazu dass man Wörter als “weiblich” eingeordnet hat, die gerade einen anderen Genus als “das Weib” haben?
Auch zu beachten wäre, dass die Benutzung des Wortes “Frau” als weibliche Form von “Mann” verhältnismäßig neuartig ist und das Genus ohnehin weiblich heißt und nicht “fraulich”.
Eine mögliche Erklärung wäre, dass man sich nach dem Genus von Tieren gerichtet hat (“der Hengst”/“die Stute”), allerdings finde ich es fragwürdig dass das Genus von Tieren als grundsätzlicher betrachtet wurde als das von Menschen. Zudem ist das weibliche Genus auch bei Tieren nicht universell (“der Hahn”/“das Huhn”).

Dafür ist ja die Sache weiblich. Nur der Mann ist von der heiteren Paradoxie ausgeschlossen. :)

Deine Frage ist eigentlich der beste Beweis dafür, dass Genus und Sexus einfach zwei verschiedene Dinge sind, die nichts miteinander zu tun haben (müssen). Im allgemeinen ist jeder Versuch, diese Verbindung herzustellen, zum Scheitern verurteilt.

Ich finde den ganzen Gedankengang sehr abwegig, dass das Wort "Weib" schon so wie heute bestanden habe, als in der Sprache die nach dieser Theorie also irgendwie schon vorher bestehenden grammatischen Geschlechter den biologischen Geschlechtern "zugeordnet" wurden.

Die Benennung der grammatischen Geschlechter durch die natürlichen wird bei den Nomen gestützt durch Paare wie:

Vater – Mutter, Sohn – Tochter, Bruder – Schwester, Onkel – Tante
Hengst – Stute, Hahn – Henne, Eber – Sau, Stier – Kuh

Außerdem natürlich durch die deiktische Verwendung der Pronomen:

Wie sie wieder guckt!
Wie er wieder guckt!


+1, Namen mit Artikeln fallen mir noch ein: Da kommt der immer fröhliche Dieter. Die Callas singt heute in der Scala. Ich bin die Martina, ne?

Die Antwort kann man eigentlich sehr kurz geben: "Das weibliche Genus" ist nicht so gemeint wie:

"das Genus, das auch das Wort 'Weib' als Genus trägt"

-- sondern es ist gemeint in der Art:

"das Genus, das eine Bedeutung hat so wie die Bedeutung des Wortes 'Weib' ist"

(Natürlich ist es nicht völlig richtig, eine Bedeutung der Genusmerkmale in dieser Art anzunehmen, solch eine Assoziation stand aber offenbar Pate bei der Benennung der Genera.)

Das setzt aber voraus, dass man sich einer anderen Bedeutung bewusst war, die unabhängig vom Genus von Weib überliefert wurde... aber wie? Wieso wusste man dass gerade das namensgebende Wort für den Genus untypisch war, und eher Wörter wie “die Stute“ (Tier) oder “die Frau” (auf einem gesellschaftlichen Rang hinweiseind) den “richtigen” Genus hatten? Wieso nicht umgekehrt?

2 Laienhafte Anmerkungen: a) Ich denke anstelle von "Bedeutung" passt hier besser das Wort "Funktion", ohne dass ich es als optimal einschätze, aber das Wortgeschlecht hat ja keine Bedeutung. Wer meint, dass das männliche Geschlecht von "Hammer" etwas zu bedeuten hat, der müsste auch zeigen können, was das weibliche der Zange bedeutet. "Hammer" und "Zange" bedeuten etwas, aber das "der" bzw. "die" bedeuten nichts, außer dass sie bedeuten, dass ich sagen muss "Der Hammer, den ich ..." vs. "Die Zange, die ich ..." (~verlegt habe). b) Das Wort "lang" ist auch nicht länger als "kurz".

Das was wir »grammatische Geschlechter« nennen, sollte vielleicht besser »Substantivklassen« heißen. Deutsch hat im Singular 3 solcher Klassen und im Plural nur eine. Die in Afrika beheimateten Bantu-Sprachen haben hingegen zum Teil mehr als 20 dieser Klassen, die im Großen und Ganzen auch nicht viel anders funktionieren als die 3 deutschen Substantiv-Klassen: Jedes Substantiv lässt sich einer Klasse zuordnen, und andere Bestandteile des Satzes (Attribute, Artikel, bei den Bantu-Sprachen sogar auch die Verben) müssen sich in ihren Endungen an diese Klassen anpassen.
Woher kommen nun die deutschen grammatischen Geschlechter?
Das fing vor tausenden von Jahren in der indogermanischen Ursprache damit an, dass man zwischen belebten und unbelebten Dingen unterschied. Belebt waren Menschen, Tiere, Götter, Geister. Unbelebt war alles andere (darunter auch alle Pflanzen). Diesen Unterschied gibt es heute noch in vielen davon abstammenden Sprachen. Zum Beispiel verwendet man im Deutschen das Fragewort »wen« um nach einem Akkusativobjekt zu fragen, wenn man erwartet, dass die Antwort ein Mensch ist. Erwartet man eine unbelebte Sache als Antwort, fragt man mit »was« nach dem Akkusativobjekt:

Wen hast du geküsst? Ich habe meine Frau geküsst.
Was hast du getrunken? Ich habe frische Milch getrunken.

Substantive, die belebte Dinge bezeichneten, wurden in der indogermanischen Ursprache mit anderen Artikeln verwendet als unbelebte Dinge. Die Substantivklasse für unbelebte Dinge ist der Vorläufer des sächlichen Geschlechts, und die Klasse für belebte Dinge ist der Vorläufer für das männliche Geschlecht, mit dem damals immer auch weibliche Lebewesen gemeint sein konnten.
Es gab neben der Unterscheidung belebt - unbelebt auch noch die Unterscheidung eines - zwei - viele. Das sind die drei Numerusklassen Singular, Dual und Plural. Den Dual findet man in den germanischen Sprachen nur mehr rudimentär, z.B. im Bairischen, wo es für die zweite Person neben den Anredeformen für eine Person (du, dia, di) (Nominativ, Dativ, Akkusativ; es gibt keinen bairischen Genitiv) und für viele Personen (iha, eich, eich) auch eine Anredeform für Paare gibt (es, enk, enk). Sonst ist der Dual aus allen Germanischen Sprachen fast vollständig verschwunden. (Auch im Bairischen wird heutzutage kaum noch zwischen Dual und Plural unterscheiden.)
Als dann in der indogermanischen Ursprache das Bedürfnis aufkam, weibliche Lebewesen von männlichen zu unterscheiden, »borgte« man sich die Deklinationsformen des Plural aus, und verwendete für die Begleitwörter von weiblichen Substantiven Formen, die sich eigentlich für den Plural herausgebildet hatten, beließ das Substantiv selbst aber in der Singular-Form. Aus diesem Grund sind die bestimmten Artikel für weibliche Substantive (die, der, der, die) (Nom, Gen, Dat, Akk) denen für den Plural auch heute noch recht ähnlich (die, der, den, die). Nur der Dativ ist anders.
Warum genau die Namen für viele unbelebte Dinge im Lauf der Jahrtausende ihr Geschlecht wechselten, ist schwer nachzuvollziehen, aber für vieles, was im Wandel einer Sprache passiert, gibt es keinen logischen Grund. Natürliche Sprachen werden nicht geplant. Sie passieren.
Aber die Unterscheidungspaare belebt - unbelegt und männlich - weiblich, die sich in der indogermanischen Ursprache für den Singular herausgebildet haben, führen dazu, dass es in den modernen Germanischen Sprachen insgesamt vier grammatische Geschlechter gibt, wovon aber maximal drei zugleich in einer Sprache vorkommen. Hier sind einige Beispiele:

nur ein Geschlecht: Englisch
Nur ein Geschlecht für Substantive zu haben, bedeutet, dass es bei den Substantiven keine Geschlechtsunterscheidung gibt, was gleichbedeutend damit ist, dass es die Kategorie »Geschlecht« für Substantive gar nicht gibt. In der englischen Sprache hat diese Kategorie nur bei den Pronomen überlebt, also bei Wörtern, die Stellvertreter für Substantive sind, und deren Geschlecht ursprünglich vom Geschlecht des vertretenen Substantivs abhing (so wie im Deutschen), aber diese grammatische Abhängigkeit wurde durch eine Abhängigkeit von belebt - unbelebt und im Fall von belebt vom biologischen Geschlecht ersetzt. Aber die Substantive, die die eigentlichen Träger des Geschlechts in indogermanischen Sprachen sind, haben im Englischen kein Geschlecht mehr (bzw. alle dasselbe).

zwei Geschlechter, Version 1: Italienisch
Italienisch geht auch aus der indogermanischen Ursprache hervor, hat aber das sächliche Geschlecht verloren. Alle Substantive der italienischen Sprache sind entweder männlich oder weiblich.

zwei Geschlechter, Version 2: Schwedisch
Schwedisch hat die Unterscheidung zwischen männlich und weiblich verloren, allerdings lange nachdem die unbelegten Dinge zu anderen Geschlechtern als sächlich gewechselt haben. Daher unterscheiden die beiden schwedischen Geschlechter auch nicht zwischen belebt und unbelebt. Die beiden schwedischen Geschlechter heißen »utrum« (lateinisch: beides), das ist die Verschmelzung von weiblich und männlich, und »neutrum« (lateinisch ursprünglich »ne utrum« = »nicht beides«, also »keines von beidem«), das entspricht dem sächlichen Geschlecht der meisten anderen germanischen Sprachen.

drei Geschlechter: Deutsch
Im Deutschen haben sich alle drei Geschlechter der indogermanischen Ursprache erhalten.


Warum ist das Weib nicht weiblich, sondern sächlich?
Das ist in der Tat eine schwierige Frage, und ich fürchte, dass niemand darauf eine befriedigende Antwort geben kann. Schon die Herkunft des Wortes ist unklar. Man weiß, dass es mittelhochdeutsch »wip« und althochdeutsch »wib« war, und es wird diskutiert, ob die ursprüngliche Bedeutung »die Verhüllte« war, aber das wird von vielen Experten angezweifelt. Noch weniger Anhänger hat die Deutung »die, die sich bewegt«. Aber dazu, woher der sächliche Artikel kommt, konnte ich leider gar nichts finden. Ich fürchte, dass man es schlichtweg nicht weiß.
Warum sollte man das Neutrum nicht das weibliche Geschlecht nennen?
Weil »Neutrum«, wie oben schon erwähnt, »keines von beiden« (Lateinisch "ne utrum" = nicht beides) bedeutet. Also weder maskulin noch feminin.
Der Fachausdruck für das grammatische weibliche Geschlecht ist »feminin«, was sich vom lateinischen »femina« ableitet, das »Frau« bedeutet. Man könnte auf die Idee kommen, dieses Geschlecht »fraulich« zu nennen, aber dieses Adjektiv bezeichnet eher die Wirkung einer Person nach außen, während »weiblich« bei Lebewesen eine biologische Zugehörigkeit beschreibt. Eine Kuh, eine Sau, eine Stute und eine Henne sind weiblich, aber nicht fraulich. Ebenso ist ein Mädchen im Babyalter zwar weiblich, aber keineswegs fraulich.
Auch wenn das Substantiv »Weib« sächlich ist, ist das davon abgeleitete Adjektiv »weiblich« genau das richtige Wort, um jene Substantivklasse zu bezeichnen, die weder männlich noch sächlich ist.

Danke für die ausführliche Antwort, allerdings ist die Umformulierung der Frage als “Warum sollte man das Neutrum nicht das weibliche Geschlecht nennen?” ungenau. Die Frage ist eher, wieso Weib, Huhn, Meer usw. nicht “weiblich/feminin” heißen sollten, und “Sonne”, “Stute”, “Armee”, usw. nicht “neutrum”? Das ist selbstverständlich kein Sprachbegrauchvorschlag, sondern eine Frage nach dem Hintergrund der jetzigen Einordnung. Wieso wurde “die” und nicht “das” als weiblich eingeordnet? Das lateinische “feminin” klärt das auch nicht weil die “femina” im Deutschen eben “das Weib” war.

Diese Antwort ist unrichtig. Man unterschied nicht zwischen "belebten und unbelebten" Dingen, sondern zwischen solchen, die als Objekt eines Satzes auftreten (m-Stämme) und solchen, die als Subjekt auftreten (s-Stämme). Und das geschah auch nicht "in der indogermanischen Ursprache" per se an, sondern ist eine spät-indogermanische Erfindung, wie etwa der Vergleich der anatolischen Sprachfamilie mit den anderen zeigt.

Eine sehr schöne Antwort! Zum Neutrum "das Weib" könnte vielleicht beigetragen haben, dass man in manchen Kulturen und Gesellschaften Frauen als Eigentum betrachtete. In England konnten noch bis ins 19. Jahrhundert hinein verheiratete Männer anstatt einer Scheidung ihre Frau an einen anderen Mann verkaufen, um sie los zu werden.

@ASlateff: Was hat Eigentum mit dem grammatikalischen Geschlecht zu tun? Wenn jemand ein weibliches Tier besitzt (z.B. eine Stute, eine Henne, eine Kuh, ...) dann wird dieses Tier dadurch, dass man es besitzt, doch nicht sächlich. Und das, was in Bezug auf das Eigentum der Patriarchen für Ehefrauen galt, galt auch für deren Töchter, und die waren auch nicht sächlich.

Tatsächlich werden in Österreich Tiere rechtlich als „Sachen“ behandelt. Ich denke, dass es einen Objekt-Aspekt gab, Eigentum als Objekte zu sehen.
Lustig ist auch der Genus bei vielen (Haus-)Tieren: Der Hengst/die Stute/das Pferd, der Eber/die Sau/das Schwein, der Stier/die Kuh/das Rindvieh,...

@ASlateff: Das ist falsch und das Gegenteil ist richtig. Hier ist der vollständige Wortlaut des § 285a aus dem österreichischen AGB in der am heutigen Tag gültigen Fassung: Tiere sind keine Sachen; sie werden durch besondere Gesetze geschützt. Die für Sachen geltenden Vorschriften sind auf Tiere nur insoweit anzuwenden, als keine abweichenden Regelungen bestehen. Dieser Paragraph trat übrigens schon im Juli 1988 in Kraft, ist also keineswegs neu.

Die "Entschlechtischung" (Hah!) findet man auch bei "das Kind, der Junge, das Mädchen". Ich glaube ich habe im Bayerischen auch schon "das" for weiblichen Vornamen bei jüngeren Personen gehört: "das Gretl" aber auch in "das Buberl." Interessanterweise werden aus den weiblichen Baumsorten "die Erle/Eiche/Buche/Eibe/Esche/Tanne" auch "der Wald" und "der Baum."

@R.J.Mathar: »Das Gretl« und »das Buberl« sind Diminutive, also Verkleinerungsformen, so wie auch »das Bübchen« und »das Fräulein«. Vor allem als Besitzer eines Haustiers kennt man in Österreich und Bayern auch »das Frauerl« und »das Herrl« und im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum »das Frauchen« und das »Herrchen«. Alle Diminutive sind sächlich, daher auch die genannten Wörter. Darüber hinaus gibt es im bairischen Dialektgebiet auch seit Jahrhunderten das Mensch (Plural: die Menscher mit r am Ende) als abwertende Bezeichnung für ...

... eine junge Frau. Auch zu erwähnen ist, dass in den alemannischen Dialekten bis ins 20. Jahrhundert hinein Kinder generell sächlich waren. Daher schriebt Johanna Spyri in ihren berühmten Heidi-Roman auch konsequent immer »das Heidi«, und der Titel des zweiten Heidi-Romans lautet daher auch Heidi kann brauchen, was es gelernt hat
